# Customizing notifications in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, notifications

Is there anyway to customize properties like `text-direction` or `font` in notifications created by chrome extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you'll have to create an image and draw the text on it with Canvas API, then output the result in the notification.